# How to set 2 React components under one Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I learned how to set a React component with Redux, but when I am having trouble with setting 2 components with one React store, I thought I needed to just combine reducers, but it didn't work. MyNote is a note taking component and Count is a click counter, I use Codepen, so here is what I tried. but it doesn't render, I don't know what am I missing, thank you for your help.

```
//Redux.
const ADD = "ADD";

function addNote (note) {
  return {
    type: ADD,
    note: note
  };
};
function add () {
  return {
    type: ADD
  };
};

function Reducer1(state = [], action) {
  if (action.type == ADD) {
    return [...state, action.note];
  } else {
    return state;
  }
};
function Reducer2(state = 0, action) {
  if (action.type == ADD) {
    return state + 1;
  } else {
    return state;
  }
};

const reducer = Redux.combineReducers({
  Reducer1: Reducer1,
  Reducer2: Reducer2
});
const store = Redux.createStore(reducer);

//React.
const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
const connect  = ReactRedux.connect;

class MyNote extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
    
    this.state = {
      input: "",
    }
    
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.submitNote = this.submitNote.bind(this);
  };
  
  handleChange (event) {
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value
    });
  };
  
  submitNote () {
    this.props.submitNotes(this.state.input);
    
    this.setState({
      input: ""
    });
  };
  
  render () {
    
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Little by little</h1>
        <input value = {this.state.input} onChange = {this.handleChange}/>
        <button onClick = {this.submitNote}> Add </button>
        <h1>{this.props.notes.map(function (item) {
            return (<li>{item}</li>)
          })}</h1>
      </div>)
  }
};
class Count extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
    
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClick (event) {
    this.props.addOne();
  };
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick = {this.handleClick}>Count</button>
        <h1>{this.props.number}</h1>
      </div>)
  }
};
class Presentational extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyNote />
        <Count />
      </div>);
  }
};

//react-redux.
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    notes: state
  };
};
function mapStateToProps2 (state) {
  return {
    number: state
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    submitNotes: function (note) {
      dispatch(addNote(note));
    }
  }
};
function mapDispatchToProps2 (dispatch) {
  return {
    addOne: function () {
      dispatch(add()); 
    }
  };
};

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyNote);
const Container2 = connect(mapStateToProps2, mapDispatchToProps2)(Count);

class AppWrapper extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return(
      <Provider store = {store}>
        <Presentational />
      </Provider>);
  }  
};

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store = {store}>
        <Presentational />
      </Provider>, document.getElementById("element1"));
```

Comment: why are you connecting them to the same component? you could have just done :
`connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyNotes)` instead, and then used a subsection of the redux state in your code.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar Still doesn't work, thank you for your comment though.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar How do I use a subsection of the redux state?

Comment: you can simply do : `return { notes: state.Reducer1 } ` in your `mapStateToProps` function, as you have `combineReducers` available, this will ensure that you are only accessing that "subset" for your components, i'd also recommend that you switch to react hooks if possible, if you're new, you should learn class based components for history, but for the new stuff, hooks will make your life easier 

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar I changed the mapStateToProps but it still doesn't work.